# Why local.xml always use <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>?

Tags: database, magento-1, local.xml, localhost

I want to see what database a Magento installation was using. If i observe the file **/public_html/app/etc/local.xml**

Surprisingly, it shows a database that doesn't exist, even my hosting server is justhost.com it is showing  ?

How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Look for the host server of the database. This will be visible between the  tags. In my example, it's localhost.

```
<connection>
      <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
      <username><![CDATA[magento_db_user]]></username>
      <password><![CDATA[password12]></password>
      <dbname><![CDATA[magento_db]]></dbname>
```

Comment: It shows localhost

Comment: What happens when you clear the cache **after** doing a pair of database backups?

Answer (score 0):

You can find more info on this page
https://my.justhost.com/cgi/help/mojomarketplace

Please find this part:
"
Hostname: The name of the host where the database is located. If the database is on your Just Host account then it would be "localhost "
Username: The database username.
Password: The password for the database username.
Database Name: The name of the database
"
So yes " localhost " sounds about right and 
I think database name is generated automatically :) there you are not aware of it :)

Comment: what do you mean "generated automatically"? If the name is generated automatically, wouldn't I be able to see it in phpmyadmin from my hosting company?

Answer (score 0):

By saying it is generated automatically i mean you probably used the option to do so:

In your hosting manual it says :
"

> Automatically create a new database
>
> If using this option, the MOJO Marketplace installer will
>   automatically create the database and database username for you. If
>   you choose to use your own database you will need to create it first

"
I do think you should see it on phpmyadmin page.
If I was you I would contact your hosting provider and ask about this.
They should clear things out for you.
If your magento webshop is up and running 
It is driven by real and not a ghost database ;) for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You should contact your hosting provider to ask them why you do not have access to the database of your Magento store as they will be the only one who can tell you why the database *doesn't exist*.

Answer (score 0):

The actual database Magento is running on can be different from the settings in local.xml for several reasons:

- `local.xml` was updated but the Config Cache was not cleared
- There is an other `.xml` file in `app/etc/` which contains the settings. All `*.xml` files in that dir are loaded as config.